# Multiple models to json

Tags: json, windows-runtime, json.net, windows-8.1

Is there a way to create a json array string from multiple models for Windows 8.1 Store App. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string property1 {get;set;}
    public string property2 {get;set;}
}

public class Foo2
{
    public string value1 {get;set;}
    public string value2 {get;set;}
}
```

I have multiple models. I'm using json.net to convert models to json string. I can also convert arrays of models.
My question is how can I create an array json string using these models like:

```
[
    {
        "property1":"string",
        "property2":"string"
    },
    {
        "value1":"string",
        "value2":"string"
    },
    {
        "property1":"string",
        "property2":"string"
    }
]
```

I'm really stuck and need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create abstract class `BaseFoo` that both `Foo` and `Foo2` classes will inherit from:

```
public abstract class BaseFoo
{

}

public class Foo : BaseFoo
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Foo2 : BaseFoo
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say that you initialize the list like this:

```
 var list = new List<BaseFoo>
     {
         new Foo
         {
             property1 = "prop11",
             property2 = "prop12"
         },
         new Foo2
         {
             value1 = "val1",
             value2 = "val2"
         },
         new Foo
         {
             property1 = "prop21",
             property2 = "prop22"
         }
     };
```

The serialization should look like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

And the produced `json` will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "$type": "ConsoleApplication23.Foo, ConsoleApplication23",
        "property1": "prop11",
        "property2": "prop12"
    },
    {
        "$type": "ConsoleApplication23.Foo2, ConsoleApplication23",
        "value1": "val1",
        "value2": "val2"
    },
    {
        "$type": "ConsoleApplication23.Foo, ConsoleApplication23",
        "property1": "prop21",
        "property2": "prop22"
    }
]
```

The `TypeNameHandling.Objects` option is added for successful deserialization:

```
var deserializedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BaseFoo>>(json, settings);
```

You can exclude it and get the exact json string you need, if you do not need to deserialize it back. Although leaving it included shouldn't break any functionality but will increase the size of the json string.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and let you know about result.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it works for me! I don't need TypeNameHandling.Objects option because I need this for a response. Thank you for answering again.

Comment: Can't you just do a `List<object>`?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you can also put anything in a `List<object>`